# how to paginate data in ionic4 app with ngx-pagination?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

I follow the commands of this page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pagination) to put ngx-pagination in my ionic app.I got this error.It seems the ngx-pagination package hasn't been installed successfully.Is there any other solution?

ERROR:
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'pagination-controls' is not a known element:
1. If 'pagination-controls' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'pagination-controls' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (" [ERROR ->]"): ng:///LoginPageModule/MenuPage.html@116:27
Error: Template parse errors:
'pagination-controls' is not a known element:
1. If 'pagination-controls' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'pagination-controls' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import {IonicStorageModule} from '@ionic/storage';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {IonicSelectableModule} from 'ionic-selectable';
import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {EditCustomerPage} from './pages/edit-customer/edit-customer.page';


// import {MenuPage} from './pages/menu/menu.page';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, EditCustomerPage],
  entryComponents: [EditCustomerPage],
  imports: [ BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    IonicSelectableModule,

    ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,

    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})
export class AppModule {}
```

menu.page.html

```
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
```

menu.module.ts

```
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {IonicSelectableModule} from 'ionic-selectable';
import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination';


import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import {ModalController} from '@ionic/angular';
import {EditCustomerPageModule} from '../edit-customer/edit-customer.module';



// import { MenuPage } from './menu.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  // {
  //   path: 'menu',
  //   component: MenuPage,
  //   children : [
  //     { path: 'first',
  //       loadChildren: '../first/first.module#FirstPageModule' },
  //     { path: 'second',
  //       loadChildren: '../second/second.module#SecondPageModule' },
  //   ]
  // },
  {
    path : '',
    redirectTo : '/menu'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    EditCustomerPageModule,
    IonicSelectableModule,

      ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
      ModalController
  ],

})
export class MenuPageModule {}
```

Comment: Is your MenuPage component declared in the same module as AppModule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are lazy loading menu page. In which case you have to import `NgxPaginationModule` in `menu.module.ts`

Note: Make sure your component is declared in the same module where you import NgxPaginationModule

Comment: I have imported NgxPaginationModule in menu.module.ts

Comment: Can you also add your `menu.module.ts` file here?

Comment: I've copied the menu.module.ts on the top.

Comment: I think everything perfectly fine in that. Can you make sure its installed correctly check you node_modules folder to see if there is folder `ngx-pagination` in it

Comment: And why have you commented out import of `menu.page`. Make sure your component is declared in the same module where you import `ngx-pagination`

Comment: I've checked the node_module.There is ngx-pagination in that.

Comment: Try un-commenting the line `import { MenuPage } from './menu.page';` on top and adding `MenuPage` in `declarations` array in `Menu Module`. This maybe the last thing that i can spot.

Comment: I've imported ngx-pagination in the app.module and I have imorted menu page in the login module bacause of lazy loading.Do you mean I shoud have imported menu module in the app module?

Comment: You just need to make sure you import `NgxPaginationModule` in the same module in which `MenuPage` is present in `declarations` array. if its declared in `MenuModule` than `NgxPaginationModule` should be imported there if its declared in `LoginModule` than that's where `NgxPaginationModule` should be imported

Comment: It's awesome .Thanke you so much.it worked perfectly when I imported NgxPaginationModule in the login module.The module that I had declared menu module.Thanks a lot.